# Typo3: Display user specific Json file after login

Tags: json, frontend, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Basically I want to make an extension  that loads json files from a directory, loops through them and displays names and thumb-urls after a user has logged in. I don't understand where I should code this, I tried making an extension with the extension builder and work from there but I am lost.
My show function in the MediaListController:

```
    public function showAction(\Plaspack\PlaspackJson2media\Domain\Model\MediaList $mediaList)
{
    $currentUser = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uname'];
    $filepath = "json/mediaData_";
    $filepath .= $currentUser;
    $filepath .= ".json";
    $result = file_get_contents ($filepath);
    $json = json_decode($result,true);
    print_r($json);
    $mediaItems = $json[1];
    foreach ($mediaItems as $key => $mediaItem){
        echo $mediaItem["name"] . ", " . $mediaItem["url"]. "," . $mediaItem["thumbUrl"] ."<br>";
    }
    $this->view->assign('mediaList', $mediaList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like it is doable.

don't forget caching:
by default caching is done for user-groups, not on a per user base.
You should exclude your plugin/JSON-File from general caching and might do a caching by your own using the user-id as cache-tag.

---

you are on the right way. 
consider: no `echo` or `print_r` in any TYPO3 functions!
because TYPO3 always stores the output in a string-variable which gets enhanced and enhanced until the string is shown in the end. Because of this every `echo` will start the output and any configuration for the head will be to no avail.

have a look at the methods created by the extension builder: which method does a `return $stringvar`? which method stores the result in a variable (like `$this->view->assign()`)?

in your example you do `echos` but does not assign anything from the data you just fetched.
what about a `$this->view->assign('mediaList', $mediaItems);` to assign your current list to the fluid variable `mediaList`?

additional thoughts:
don't use the field `username` (`uname`?) to distinguish users, use `uid`, usernames could be changed, users could be deleted and a new user could select the deleted name.

why do you choose JSON-files? in your extension you could enhance the database fe_users table for a list of filelinks.

last: where is your caching? at least disable std caching, better: enter user specific cache tags

Comment: Honestly I am lost. Where would I start if I used option 1: a custom content element? I am assuming there is no extension that does something like this yet

Comment: custom content element = FE-Plugin. make an extension (e.g. extension builder), this extension defines additional fields where your user-information can be stored, and it defines at least one uncached(!) plugin which creates the files(?) and also creates the content for the currently active/logged in user.

Comment: I created an extension with extension builder, with 3 domains(user, mediaList, media) and the plugin. My remaining questions are:
- In which files do I  add the additional fields for the user-information
- where do I put my code to process the files in the plugin?
Sorry, still a Typo 3 newbie so all of this is getting a big knot in my brain here.

Comment: your user will map to the build in table `fe_users`. so either you enhance `fe_users` directly or link `fe_users` to your users.

Comment: I updated my original post with the code that is supposed to load the json file, still don't know where the code should be, in which file.